# How to use Angular with Require in javascript classes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I have been playing around with angular and would like to add it to application using require. I have a class called Test that is wrapped around a require for Angular. The problem is that if I do not initialize the angular.module directly under the require statement for angular, I get an error saying Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.3/require.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     require.config({
         paths: {
             "angular": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min"
            }
        });
    </script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Name: <input ng-model="name">
    <h1>You entered: {{name}}</h1>
    </div>
    <script>
    require(['angular'], function () {
     var Test = class Test {
      constructor() {
       this.setAngular();
      };

      setAngular() {
       var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
       app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "John Doe";
       });
      }
     }
    });
    var test = new Test();
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

However, if I move the require statement down to inside the setAngular function like so:

```
setAngular() {
        require(['angular'], function () {
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.name = "John Doe";
            });
        });
}
```

Then everything works fine. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You're defining Test inside a function, you can't create instance of it outside that function. Try putting `var test = new Test();` inside of require.